# npgsql preferred connection pooling usage

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I've been noticing connection pool being exhausted...I dont get full blown exception because its happening  behind web app... but basically

Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestCOnnector(Npgsql.MpgsqlConnection)

My web app basically breaks, and fails to create any new connections. If I restart web app server, or database engine, things start to work again for a short time. My connectionstring specifies min 15 connections in the pool, 30 max.

My question is in the context of a web application I should be able to just get a connection

```
using(var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring)){
    connection.open(); 
    dostuff();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Disabling pooling ends up working, and performing well, but seems like the wrong way to solve this problem.

Comment: you might not reuse connection, but each time open a new one, thus after some time reach maximum opened sessions in postgres. what is inside postgres logs?..

Comment: You seem to be using Npgsql correctly (I'm assuming your not opening any other connections). You might be having a PostgreSQL side performance issues, where queries are so slow you end up with 30 connections stuck. Analyze your PG logs as @VaoTsun suggested. Note we plan to work on an Npgsql feature to help analyze the state of the pool.

Comment: When I was working with connection pool tests, I noticed I started to get problems when I opened more than 17 concurrent connections to the same database. Postgresql started to say that the remaining slots were to be used by superuser accounts. I could find documentation about the max number of concurrent connections to the server. By default it is 100, but this value can be changed based on the capabilities of your machine. In my dev machine it seemed to be reduced to 20. Check out http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html for more info. I hope it helps.